# Rename associated files in a folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to rename files in a folder which all bear the same name but different extensions. I've searched everywhere for a solution. So far I have written the following code but it does not rename the files.. any ideas would be much appreciated??

```
void someFunction(){

        char drive[_MAX_DRIVE]; 
        char dir[_MAX_DIR]; 
        char fname[_MAX_FNAME]; 
        char ext[_MAX_EXT];

        _splitpath(m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir(), drive, dir, fname, ext);

    CString fpath(_T(m_DirTree.GetCurrentDir()));

    CString filenameWithoutExtension = fpath.Left(fpath.ReverseFind(_T('.')));

    CString fileContainer = fpath.Left(fpath.ReverseFind(_T('\\')));    // eg. L:\PowerStar 5 Demo II\Programs\Demo\Programs

    fpath = fileContainer + _T("\\");                                   // eg. L:\PowerStar 5 Demo II\Programs\Demo\Programs\

    CString fileN = fpath + fname + _T(".***");                         // eg. L:\PowerStar 5 Demo II\Programs\Demo\Programs\TestX.***


    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(fpath, &data);

    if( h!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
    {
        do
        {

        CString hpath = (fpath + myPRGName +  _T(".***"));                 // eg. L:\PowerStar 5 Demo II\Programs\Demo\Programs\TestY.*** 

        rename(fileN, hpath);   

        } while(FindNextFile(h,&data));
    } 
    else {

        cout << "Error: No such folder." << endl;

    }
        FindClose(h);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The below code might work out for you.**

```html
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\DirectoryToAccess");
FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
foreach(FileInfo f in infos)
{
    File.Move(f.FullName, f.FullName.ToString().Replace("abc","xyz"));
}
```